# Laravel join database table with where clause and like from $request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```html
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        
        if ($request->get('search') != '') {


            $franchise = DB::table('operators')
                ->join('franchises', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('operators.id', '=', 'franchises.operator_id')
                        ->where('case_number', 'like', '%' . $request->get('search') . '%');
                })
                ->get();


            return view('franchise-home', compact('franchise'));

        } else {

            $franchise = DB::table('operators')
                ->join('franchises', 'operators.id', '=', 'franchises.operator_id')
                ->get();

            return view('franchise-home', compact('franchise'));
        }

    }
```

how to make this work with both where clause and get a request from a user? Any help is much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: what is your problem can you please elaborate more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add use() to access your variable, for example :

```
$search = $request->get('search'); // define it before query
...
->join('franchises', function ($join) use($search) { //use it inside
    $join->on('operators.id', '=', 'franchises.operator_id')
         ->where('case_number', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
})
```

Comment: $search = $request->get('search'); 

        $franchise = DB::table('operators')
                ->join('franchises', function ($join) use ($search) { 
                    $join->on('operators.id', '=', 'franchises.operator_id')
                        ->where('case_number', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
                })
                ->get();

        return view('franchise-home', compact('franchise'));


thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sort code

```html
public function search(Request $request) {
    $franchise = DB::table('operators')
         ->join('franchises', 'operators.id', '=', 'franchises.operator_id')
         ->when($request->get('search'), function($query) use($request) {
               $query->where('case_number', 'like', '%' . $request->get('search');
         })
         ->get();
    return view('franchise-home', compact('franchise'));
}
```